# Google Code: Where to put documentation?

Tags: google-code

I've just generated a bunch of documentation for one of my projects that I have on Google Code... but there doesn't seem to be anywhere to upload it to. What are people doing about this? Host it elsewhere, and link to it on the homepage?

Answer (score 2):

Some people use Google Code's wiki feature (example [here](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/w/list)), but a lot of other people will have separate pages for their project on Sourceforge, Github, etc. and host their documentation there. Or, you can buy some hosting and use a documentation framework. It's really a matter of preference; it all depends on how you want to do it.

Comment: Well I don't want to re-write the documentation by hand wiki-style. Does source forge let you upload .html and .css files?

Comment: I think so, yeah. Most of the hosting sites want you to use their documentation features, though... If you really want to upload HTML and CSS you wrote, you should just buy some hosting.

Comment: I've already got paid hosting... I'd just prefer to have everything all in one place.

Comment: @Mark I'd just use Google code as your version control and issue tracker, then, and keep everything else (docs, etc.) on your paid hosting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Every google code project I've seen hosts it elsewhere and links it somewhere on the homepage.

Comment: I understand this is a common solution, but if *every* project you've seen hosts it elsewhere, you must not look at a lot of projects...

Comment: Guess I should have said nearly every. I realized after reading your comment that I have seen projects that use the wiki feature... like swfobject.